# deploy solidity contract with c#

Tags: c#, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nethereum

I am developing an application on ***Ethereum*** blockchain. I use ***Solidity*** for contract and ***Nethereum c#*** library to connect to the contract. I am somehow new in Ethereum and it is my first app in blockchain!! I want to deploy my app in one ***TESTChain*** first,

- I found a private test chain from nethereum website Docs 
  ([https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nethereum-smartcontrats-gettingstarted/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4rbT.jpg))
- created my simple contract with ***Remix*** and got the ByteCode.
- Writing simple connection code to deploy and connect to the contract.

The problem is that The ***C# code does not reply anything after send request*** for deploying of contract.  here is my code

the contract is created well on remix and in running tab it works

```
  public class DeploymentTest : ContractDeploymentMessage
        {
      public static string BYTECODE = @"0x....";// removed it because of long string

      public DeploymentTest() : base(BYTECODE) { }
        }

      public async Task ConnectToTest()
            {
                var url = "https://github.com/Nethereum/TestChains";
                var pass = "0xb5b1870957d373ef0eeffecc6e4812c0fd08f554b37b233526acc331bf1544f7";
                var acc = new Account(pass);
                var chain = new Web3(acc, url);
                var deploymentMessage = new DeploymentTest();
                var deploymentHandler =  chain.Eth.GetContractDeploymentHandler<DeploymentTest>();

                 // this point just waited and does not return anything
                var transactionReceipt = await deploymentHandler.SendRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(deploymentMessage);
                var contractAddress = transactionReceipt.ContractAddress;

                }
```

Can any one help me, I don't insist in deploying with code, it can be happened by anyway but after deploying I need to connect it and call some functions.
Thanks

***EDITED***

I downloaded the TESTChain network for windows and it works fine, it seems the default port is 8545 for http:localhost. but it still does not connect to chain

```
    var web3test = new Web3(); // also tried new Web3(http://localhost:8545);
    var isMining = await web3test.Eth.Mining.IsMining.SendRequestAsync();
    var accounts = await web3test.Eth.Accounts.SendRequestAsync();
```

is that problem with my connection? I disabled my MacAfee firewall completely.

[image]

EDITED 2

I changed my machine and it works on my another laptop, I cannot find the problem. I do not know if I just Uninstall the mcaffe will it be ok or not? 
has anybody any idea about the firewall prolems or other issues?

Comment: https://github.com/Nethereum/TestChains is a repository with scripts  for launching local test chains on your computer. It's not a URL to try to connect to in your code.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just did what I read in that web page. so to what url should I connect? do you know any test network?

Comment: If you run one of those, you'll then connect to `localhost` with some port. The node you run should output the correct port.

Comment: Would you see my EDITED please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , it was in my c# code
The function which calls the code was on the wait,

```
Main()
{
TestConnection().wait(); // this is not proper 
}

so I changed it to TestConnection(); and it works
```